# How to get product pairs using pandas for each customer

Tags: python, regex, pandas, data-analysis, recommendation-engine

I want to get product pairs where consecutive products viewed by the customer in which the second product is part of the recommendations of first product.

e.g. Customer 1 viewed Product P1 and the recommendations for the product are R1-R2-R3-R4 (4 different products) and time stamp t1.

Customer 1 viewed Product P2 and the recommendations for the product(p2) are R11-R12-R13-R14 and time stamp t2.

We need the C1, P1,P2 where P2 is one of the recommendation of P1 i.e. R1/R2/R3/R4

| customer_id | product_id(viewed) | recommendation_items | time_stamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 111-098-066-555 | 10-05-2020 |
| 1 | 111 | 213-012-122 | 10-05-2020 |
| 2 | 213 | 321-98712-1212-3434-4545 | 10-05-2020 |
| 2 | 987 | 98711-4567 | 10-05-2020 |

As we can see from the above table for customer 1, he viewed product(123) and in his recommendations item 111 product was there and he also viewed that product(second row product id). But for customer 2 it is not happened. The result table looks like this:

| customer_id | product_id_1(viewed) | product_id_2(viewed) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 111 |

Can anybody provide the logic or python code. The following code suggested is matching the string even the portion of the value matches, but we need to match the entire value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use a regex to rextract the matching recommendations, then `join`:

```
g = df.groupby('customer_id')
regexes = g['product_id(viewed)'].agg(lambda x: '|'.join(x.astype(str)))
matches = (g['recommendation_items']
           .apply(lambda s: s.str.extractall(fr'\b({regexes[s.name]})\b'))
           .droplevel(['customer_id', 'match'])[0]
          )
# 0    111
# 3    987
# Name: 0, dtype: object

out = (df.join(matches.rename('product_id2(viewed)'), how='right')
         [['customer_id', 'product_id(viewed)', 'product_id2(viewed)']]
      )
```

output:

```
   customer_id  product_id(viewed) product_id2(viewed)
0            1                 123                 111
3            2                 987                 987
```

To remove self recommendation:

```
out = (df.join(matches.rename('product_id2(viewed)'), how='right')
         [['customer_id', 'product_id(viewed)', 'product_id2(viewed)']]
         .loc[lambda d: d['product_id(viewed)'].astype(str).ne(d['product_id2(viewed)'])]
      )
```

output:

```
   customer_id  product_id(viewed) product_id2(viewed)
0            1                 123                 111
```

Comment: Hi Mozway, Thank you for the answers. It looks good but I am getting null values in customer id column(nearly 80%)(though I have dropped null values), Can you please review your logic?

Comment: Before rewieving anything, can you first provide a reproducible example for which you lose the data? (please as dictionary or DataFrame constructor as the dtypes are important)

Comment: In my dataframes all dtypes are objects. I will provide you the detail.

Comment: Hello Mozway, Our code is accepting even some portion of number is matching. e.g. lets consider in first row there is 1111 instead of 111 in recommendation_items column. Then also our code is matching these two numbers as similar and the output we are getting is not correct. It should match the entire number and not the portion on it

Comment: I have changed some values for your reference(see the table). Our code is not working in this scenario.

Comment: @RajeshM you just need to add word boundaries to the regex, see update